# How to copy a report or form from one Access database to another?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I made a form in a database that I wanted to copy to another MS Access database. I can copy and paste the form design but seems like even though all the fields are copied the form width and spacing is messed up. Is there another way to copy the form design from one database to another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you can use  `Application.DoCmd.TransferDatabase` :

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft access", "C:\sourceDB.mdb", acForm ,"SourceFormName", "FormNameInDestinationDB"
```

Or less handy two steps:

1. Export in source DB

   `Application.saveAsText acForm ,"SourceFormName", "C:\fileWithForm.txt"`
2. Import in destination DB

   `Application.LoadFromText acForm ,"FormNameInDestinationDB", "C:\fileWithForm.txt"`

Comment: This works! Just wanted to let you know that you have written two SourceFormName. One on the right should be DestinationFormName to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, opfen your new Access file and go to **External Data > External Datasource > From Access File**, specify your file path (the database path where you want to copy forms etc...) and click the option **Import tables, queries, forms, reports, macros and modueles into the current database**. Next chose what you want to import and hit **OK**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but looks like there is no option to import individual forms. This imports everything

Comment: Check the tabs. You can select a single form and hit `OK` or even `Select All`. If the tab is empty your source Database doesnt have a `Table, Form, ...` in it.